# How to log out the LiveID while using ACS on Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone, access-control, acs, liveid

I am using the Access Control on the windows phone app. For some reasons I have to ask the user to log in with another account after logging in. However, usually the user will tick the box "Sign in automatically" and he will not be able to sign in using another account. Thus, I am wondering how to log out the liveID and ask the user to log in with another account again.

I did try using this:

```
this.SignInControl.SimpleWebTokenStore.SimpleWebToken = null;             
this.SignInControl.GetSimpleWebToken();
```

But not working.  Any clues on what I should do? Thanks!